# Select mysql query between date?

Tags: mysql, select, date

How to select data from mysql table past date to current date? For example, Select data from 1 january 2009 until current date ??

My column "datetime" is in datetime date type. Please help, thanks

Edit:

If let say i want to get day per day data from 1 january 2009, how to write the query? Use count and between function?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
select * from *table_name* where *datetime_column* between '01/01/2009' and curdate()
```

or using `>=` and `<=` :

```
select * from *table_name* where *datetime_column* >= '01/01/2009' and *datetime_column* <= curdate()
```

Comment: Cool. It works. LAST question: If I want to show data per day since 01/01/2009, must use count function right? Any idea how to implement?

Comment: You can use "group by" and "order by", like this:
select * from [table_name] where [datetime_column] between '01/01/2009' and curdate() group by [datetime_column] order by [datetime_column]

Comment: i tried this: SELECT *, count(*) from table WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-09-01' GROUP BY datetime;

but the count is 1. it supposed to be, 10, 5, 8 etc...

Comment: You have to include the column name you want the count of inside count().  So, you would use count(datetime) in this case.

Comment: Also, you have to make sure that you are grouping on fields with the same value.  If you have want to group all values for a date regardless of time, you will have to use the DATE() function to get the date part of the datetime.

Comment: You will want to group by Day(<datetime_column>) not just the column because the datetime field goes down to ms I believe which means you will end up with the results grouped at ms instead of day.

Comment: "SELECT * , count(datetime) FROM table WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND CURDATE() GROUP BY Day(datetime)";

It works.. COOL. My query correct right? Just want to double check?

Comment: WAIT. @CSharpAtl: If i group by day, it end up showing 31 days. E.g my date between 1-jan-09 and CURDATE(), but it shows JANuary data only? Why? What should I group?????????????

Comment: Problem solved: I group by DATE(datetime). Thanks in millions guys :)

Comment: Make sure you add `HH:MM:SS` to **end date** or you won't get any results from that date.

Answer (score 26):

All the above works, and here is another way if you just want to number of days/time back rather a entering date

```
select * from *table_name* where *datetime_column* BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)  AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `now()` like:

```
Select data from tablename where datetime >= "01-01-2009 00:00:00" and datetime <= now();
```

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but the accepted answer didn't work for me.
If you set both start and end dates manually (not using `curdate()`), make sure to **specify the hours, minutes and seconds** (`2019-12-02 23:59:59`) on the end date or you won't get any results from that day, i.e.:

This **WILL include** records from `2019-12-02`:

```
SELECT *SOMEFIELDS* FROM *YOURTABLE* where *YOURDATEFIELD* between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-02 23:59:59'
```

This **WON'T include** records from `2019-12-02`:

```
SELECT *SOMEFIELDS* FROM *YOURTABLE* where *YOURDATEFIELD* between '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-02'
```