# Date Intervals and MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, intervals

**Hello!**

Is it possible to exclude date intervals in MySQL. Let's say: I have picked two dates

```
start_date = "2013-04-02"
```

and

```
end_date = "2013-04-12"
```

The table `reservation` holds two columns for each item (items may not be with unique id's since many reservations are possible for a single item): `reserved_from` and `reserved_until` (both type = date).

Assume that for the first item

```
reserved_from = "2013-04-05"
```

and

```
reserved_until = "2013-04-07
```

Is it possible to select all items that are NOT reserved between the start date and the end date ? What about multiple reservations and special cases (`reserved_from < "start_date"`, etc. )

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select mysql query between date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Not between start_date and end_date
```

It will select all items where dates are not present in between both.