# get data between hours in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a time like this `2013-08-12 12:58:14`. Now I want hour so I use following code:

```
$date = "2013-08-12 12:58:14";
$date = strtotime($date);
$hour = date('H', $date);
```

So I get `$hour=12`; now I have a other parameter `$tohour=5` (it is user defined which value is between 1 to 24); now `12-5=7` means fetch data between  time `7 to 12`.

---

Another example:

Suppose time is `2013-08-12 01:15:23` and `$tohour=10`.
Now this time the data fetch between `2013-08-11 15:15:23` to `2013-08-12 01:15:23`.

---

So how to achieve it? I try to explain my question, but if it is not clear, please let me know or fill free to edit my question and title too.

Comment: Do you have a table in your database with timestamps?

Comment: yes, i have table  with timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL,

```
SELECT fields
FROM table
WHERE timefield BETWEEN DATE_SUB('$date', INTERVAL $tohour HOUR) AND '$date'
```

Comment: what  is your `$todate` value?.did you mean `$tohour`?

Comment: Er, SELECT 1 BETWEEN 3 AND 0; -> 0

Comment: ya true..this query works when i interchange it so please update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the from and to times using strtotime:

```
$baseTime = strtotime('2013-08-12 01:15:23');
$from = strtotime('+'.$hour.' hours',$basetime);
$to = strtotime('+'.$tohour.' hours',$basetime);
echo "From: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$from)."\n";
echo "To: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$to)."\n";
```

Or in mysql:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   `table`
WHERE
    `time` 
BETWEEN
    DATE_ADD('$time',INTERVAL $hour HOUR)
AND
    DATE_ADD('$time',INTERVAL $tohour HOUR)
```

Comment: i try your query,it's look like `SELECT * FROM cdr where calldate BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2012-08-29 23:00:00',INTERVAL 23 HOUR) AND DATE_ADD('2012-08-29 23:00:00',INTERVAL 5 HOUR)` but it didnot fetch data .

Comment: in database, data is between `2012-08-29 21:18:23` to `2012-08-29 21:49:23`.

Comment: That basically translates to this query: SELECT * FROM cdr WHER calldate BETWEEN '2012-08-30 22:00:00' AND '2012-08-30 04:00:00' Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

In plain PHP:

```
$toHour = 10;
$dateTo = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-08-12 12:58:14');
$dateFrom = clone $dateTo;
$dateFrom->sub(new \DateInterval('PT'.$toHour.'H'));
var_dump(
    'From: ' . $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'To: ' . $dateTo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

But personally I would go with MySQL solution.

PS. Ofcourse this solution is for PHP 5 >= 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I prefered to do some compute in PHP and use simple mysql query.

```
$timeEnd = '2013-08-12 01:15:23';
$toHour = 10;

$timeStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($timeEnd) - $toHour * 3600);

echo "Fetch data between $timeStart to $timeEnd";
// Result: Fetch data between 2013-08-11 15:15:23 to 2013-08-12 01:15:23
```

Then, we got 2 date string, do db query with them, see:

- [Select mysql query between date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date)
- [How do I query between two dates using MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/mysql-query-between-two-dates)