# SQLite query between dates

Tags: android, sqlite

```
select * from table_my where my_date between '2014-07-23 00:00:00' and '2014-07-30 00:00:00' order by _id desc
```

Here is my query, I d like to create this simple date compare query, but not working. This query don't add anything out. Why? How can I compare dates in sqlite?

Comment: SQLite does not have a `DateTime` datatype! To compare dates get the epoch time from the `Date` with `getTime()` (it's a long) and save that instead in the database. Comparing two numbers is obviously very easy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date

Sometimes answers can come about through a google search.

Comment: @bhuvan-venkatesh and sometimes SQLite behaves different than MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query using [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) date functions.

```
SELECT * from table_my
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', my_date )
     between  
          strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-07-23') 
          and 
          strftime ('%Y-%m-%d', '2014-07-30');
```

---

**EDIT:**

To use with hours and minutes, you can try something like:

```
SELECT * from table_my
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M', my_date )
     between  
          strftime('%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M', '2014-07-23 11:22') 
          and 
          strftime ('%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M', '2014-07-23 11:25');
```

Comment: It looks like this working, but Can u help me how to use this to use minutes in this query? So: yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM (2014-07-23 11:22 and between  2014-07-23 11:25)

Comment: You can use `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', my_date )`

Comment: @lacas: Refer edit. Please **upvote** and **accept as answer** if it helped you..

Comment: Thanks now it is working, my code look like this       String sql = "SELECT * from "+SQLLiteHelper.TABLE_MY +" WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', mdate ) between  strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '"+nnow+"') and strftime ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '"+nnowminus+"')";

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_my where my_date between '2014-07-30' and '2014-07-23' order by _id desc
```

use above query may it will work to you i also got such kind of problem during coding i think it is coming cause your using lower value before greater value

may it will help you just chek it

i just swiped the two dates also i removed timestamp