# what is the query to get mysql rows from two dates between statement

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get some value from my mysql database between two dates.
my database field is created_at = 2015-02-24 18:58:19

so what it the sql statement to get rows from two date;
my date input pattern is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select mysql query between date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, 1 which is easier to read but slower, and one harder to read but faster:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(created_at) IN ('2015-02-24', '2015-02-26')
```

and second:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2015-02-24 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-24 23:59:59') OR (created_at BETWEEN '2015-02-26 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-26 23:59:59')
```

And if you always have 2 or more consecutive dates, it's better to change the between to, so on the 24th or 25th:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2015-02-24 00:00:00' AND '2015-02-25 23:59:59')
```