# How to select minimum time and maximum time of a day in a field?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I want to list min time and max time of a day in for each users from the below table.

How to fetch records like below.

**Expected result:**

```
user_id  FROM                 TO
-------- -------------------  -------------------
6        2015-01-22 11:30:51  2015-01-22 16:30:51
17       2015-01-22 11:59:31  2015-01-22 11:59:31
17       2015-01-30 05:52:30  2015-01-30 06:07:47
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select mysql query between date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date)

Comment: `select \`user_id\`, date(\`date\`), min(\`date\`), max(\`date\`) from table group by \`user_id\`,date(\`date\`)` perhaps?

Comment: Thank you @MarkBaker. I get my expected result using your query :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You didn't include a table name.

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(date) AS 'FROM', MAX(date) AS 'TO' FROM <table> GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: If you want the min/max "time" of the day: SELECT user_id, DATE_FORMAT(MIN(date), '%H:%i:%s') AS `FROM`, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(date), '%H:%i:s') AS `TO` FROM table GROUP BY user_id

Comment: @ggioffreda Does it matter whether or not he uses DATE_FORMAT since the columns themselves are already in the format he wants?

Comment: I've edited the comment while you were replying :) it was just in case he actually meant "I want to list min time and max time of a day". I know it contradicts the expected result, but it doesn't harm