# sql query replace NOW() to datetime

Tags: sql, date, timezone, utc

I have a request:

```
SELECT 
  *,
  CASE WHEN NOW() BETWEEN `from` AND `to` THEN "1" ELSE "0" END AS status, 
FROM
  `table`
WHERE
  NOW() > `created_at`
```

And I would like to replace NOW() to my $date variable (UTC).
How can I change my request?

P.S My query little bit changed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're speaking about MySQL, which I think we are based on this syntax, this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE  $date > `created_at`
```

Modified from another question, [source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date)

**EDIT**

New query:

```
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN $date BETWEEN `from` AND `to` THEN "1" 
ELSE "0" 
END 
AS status, 
FROM `table`
WHERE
$date > `created_at`
```

Comment: Why did you place "=" instead?

Comment: and as he also mentioned that $date is in UTC

Comment: @ChiragThakar I editetd my question, thank you. How does the date being UTC has any influence on this?

Comment: UTC is a standard time, and timezone is varying as per the region, so we need to make sure about his 'created_at' is in UTC format, make sense?

Comment: @ChiragThakar I see, yes, I thought that's oblivious. If he ever comes back saying there's a problem with the format, that'd probably be the mistake. (: