# SQL Query to select data between particular date and time dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, database

Kindly provide me SQL query:

We want to select all details from a table where date is equal to particular date and time is between some time period(dynamically).

For example I wish to get all the details of the students where they registered in particular date between particular time.

Comment: You could of solved this through a simple Google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_stu WHERE reg_date = '$date' AND reg_time >= '$time_1' AND reg_time <= '$time_2'";
?>
```