# Case with dates between now and 2 days?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to list out a table, and if a schedule date is within 2 days, to list as a warning and if the date is past today then list it as late.

I'm having trouble getting the "Between" portion of this code to function properly.  The between code seems to work outside the case statement but not within.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

```
SELECT schedule,
case when schedule BETWEEN(curdate(), curdate() + 2)then 1 else 0 end as 
 warning,
case when schedule < CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end as late
 from upgrade_table
```

> error: 
>       Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
>       syntax to use near 'then 1 else 0 end as warning,
>       case when sched < CURDATE() then 1 else 0 end as l' at line 2

Comment: Does it error? Does it produce the wrong answer?

Comment: Between syntax is `BETWEEN value AND value`

Comment: Don't just post "I'm having trouble". Quote the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select mysql query between date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date)

Comment: Right, so you need to fix the syntax, as @RiggsFolly said 11 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for the BETWEEN is:

```
BETWEEN [FirstValue] AND [SecondValue]
```

Ex:

```
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2+DAY(2)
```