# Complex Queries range dates

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> mySQL dateTime range Query Issue

how get count of proceser in 2017 by same date like 2017-08-07

> ---
>
> > ```
> > date         | name      
> > -----------------------
> >  2017-08-31   |  amr
> > -----------------------
> >  2017-08-05   |  ahmed
> > ----------------- -----
> >      2018-08-08   | moh
> >
> > how get 2017-01-01 BETWEEN 2017-12-31
> > ------------------------
> > count         | date      
> > -----------------------
> >  2            |  2017
> > -----------------------
> >      1            | 2018
> > ```

```
  SELECT  count(*)
    FROM item WHERE  
    date IN 
    ( SELECT  date 
     FROM item WHERE 
     (BETWEEN '2017-03-15' AND '2017-09-31'))
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date

Comment: no my proplem diffrent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select mysql query between date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date)

Comment: @AmrEssam How? Update your question to show why it is different.

Comment: @DuaneLortie the appropriate action would be to click "flag" under the post, and go to "a duplicate...", where you would post the link. This flags the question and allows it to be resolved quicker.

Comment: i update see question

Comment: Are you saying you want to GROUP BY and COUNT using different date ranges?  There's got to be a duplicate for that hanging around here somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a duplicate for you, but I am sure there is one somewhere.

If you use `GROUP BY` and the `DATE_FORMAT()` function, you can `COUNT()` the occurrences in each group.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y') FROM `item` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y');
```

You can include a `WHERE` clause before `GROUP BY` if you need to omit certain ranges of time.

Answer (score 0):

1, date is a reserved MySQL word. It would be best to name your column something else, but you can use it if you also specify the table name like `table.date`

2, there is no need for a sub-query. MySQL can do this in one query

```
SELECT count(`table.name`) as NUMBER, YEAR(`table.date`) as YR FROM item WHERE DATE(`table.date`) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN is kind of a "ternary" operator, of the form `x BETWEEN y AND z`

You want:

```
`date` BETWEEN '2017-03-15' AND '2017-09-31'
```

Comment: `date` BETWEEN '2017-03-15' AND '2017-09-31' 
and 

`date` BETWEEN '2018-03-15' AND '2018-09-31'

Comment: You'd need "OR" not "and"; a single date cannot be in multiple non-overlapping date ranges any more than 2 can be in 1-3 AND 3-4.