# MySQL Select query between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql table called contracts. I try to filter contracts applicable between two dates **2022-05-03** and **2022-05-07**. MySQL query must be return id numbers: `1`,`2`,`3` because all record have at least one contract applicable day in filter data. Any pointers into the right direction would be helpful. Thanks!

`SELECT id FROM contracts WHERE ...`

**contracts table**

```
|     id    | start_date |  end_date  |
|      1    | 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-04 |
|      2    | 2022-05-06 | 2022-05-10 |
|      3    | 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-10 |
```

**calendar visualisation**

```
| id  | 05/01 | 05/02 | 05/03 | 05/04 | 05/05 | 05/06 | 05/07 | 05/08 | 05/09 | 05/10 |
|  1  |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|  2  |       |       |       |       |       |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |
|  3  |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |   x   |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select mysql query between date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469689/select-mysql-query-between-date)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need a query that can "detect" 4 possibilities:
{1} start before the interval (start <-> end), end inside the interval
{2} start and end inside the interval
{3} start inside the interval, end after the interval
{4} start before the interval, end after the interval

```
                 start                        end
-------------------|---------------------------|--------------

{1} ----------|------------|----------------------------------

{2} -------------------|---------------|----------------------

{3} ------------------------------|--------------------|------

{4} ----------|-----------------------------------|-----------
```

Thus:

```
select id
from Contracts 
where 
( start_date <= '2022-05-03' and ( end_date >= '2022-05-03' and end_date <= '2022-05-07' ) ) 
or
( start_date >= '2022-05-03' and end_date <= '2022-05-07' ) 
or
( ( start_date >= '2022-05-03' and start_date <= '2022-05-07' ) and end_date >= '2022-05-07' )
or
( start_date <= '2022-05-03' and end_date >= '2022-05-07' )
;
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=63ce7310d0e8fc0d0628cac7a0ace646) here (data set slightly larger than your sample data).

**EDIT**

As @WOUNDEDStevenJones has suggested, the following query is easier to code and understand, AND will deliver reliable results:

```
select id
from Contracts 
WHERE start_date <= '2022-05-07' AND end_date >= '2022-05-03'
;
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2c0836460fa44f516fc4ae7517a2329e)

Comment: One way this can be simplified is to check `WHERE start_date <= '2022-05-07' AND end_date >= '2022-05-03'` instead of the 4 conditions separately.

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2c0836460fa44f516fc4ae7517a2329e for a working example (with all 4 of your example cases, plus 1 with both start/end before 2022-05-03, and 1 with both start/end after 2022-05-07).

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones brilliant!  Thanks for your suggestion.  May I add your solution into my answer?

Comment: absolutely, go for it

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`SELECT id FROM Contracts WHERE start_date BETWEEN 2022-05-03 and 2022-05-07 ORDER BY start_date;`

Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: It's about a range ie an interval between the start and end, which should be compared to another range (not just a start_date).

Answer (score -1):

this should work

```
SELECT id FROM `Contracts ` WHERE 
(DATE(start_date) >= '2022-05-03' || DATE(start_date) <= '2022-05-03') ||
(DATE(end_date) >= '2022-05-07' || DATE(end_date) <= '2022-05-07')
```

Comment: Wouldn't that select all data with a valid `start_date` or `end_date`? You have `WHERE (start >= 3 OR start <= 3) OR (end >= 7 OR end <= 7)`